# Mootools 1.2 Custom Tooltip Error - Tooltips show image before hover

Tags: javascript, mootools, tooltip

Having a bit of an issue woth mootools 1.2 Tips (cutsom tooltips)

We are using Joomla with the latest update that includes Mootools 1.2 - and I have the following JS code

```
    $$('.tipz').each(function(element,index) {
      var content = element.get('title').split('::');
          element.store('tip:title', content[0]);
      element.store('tip:text', content[1]);
    });

    var tipz = new Tips($$('.tipz'), {
          className: 'tipz',
          fixed: true,
      hideDelay: 50,
      showDelay: 50        
        });
```

My problem is that the background images I styled the tips with is showing up wether I mouse over the tip or not - its quite annoying.

Has anyone else had this problem/ knows a fix for it?

Thanks in advance,

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your CSS background property is on the hover status of your tooltip

```
tool-tip:hover { background: ... }
```

Or

```
tool-tip:hover tool-text { background: ... }
```